# One hundred balls are tosses into 50 boxes what is the excepted number of balls in the tenth box? According to Bernoulli trail

Tags: probability

According to Bernoulli trail
Why we have to use Bernoulli trail??why can't we solve normally?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: What "normal" solution did you have in mind?  The Bernoulli method is awfully easy...or just use symmetry.

Comment: @lulu I hope that the underlying thoughts of the OP were something like: "why not just symmetry?..."

Comment: @drhab  Well, sure.  That's what I was hoping the OP would say in response.  As opposed to "using the normal approximation".

Answer (score 1):

For $i=1,\dots,100$ let $X_i$ take value $1$ if ball $i$ arrives at the $10$-th box and let it take value $0$ otherwise.

Then $X=\sum_{i=1}^{100}X_i$ equals the number of balls that arrive in the $10$-th box.

Now find $\mathbb EX$ by applying linearity of expectation and symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

The expected number must be the same for all boxes and is therefore $2$.